# Best practice for native login in the app from a webview?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, session, cookies

I am searching for a good solution to login a user via webview into the native part of the app.

On my Webserver I have a dynamically login page and this page I want to use also for the login into my app. So that I don't need a release via AppStore, when I change some parts here.

But with the session cookie storage I have sometimes the problem that the cookie from the website is not in the cookie storage of the webview. There are different solutions and I tried them, but in the end with moderate success.

I tried session cookies, java script and own header field.

Comment: That's a bad design.

Comment: Any suggestions?